# Updating a list of python dictionaries with a key, value pair from another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have the following list of python dictionary:

```
dict1 = [{'domain':'Ratios'},{'domain':'Geometry'}]
```

and a list like:

```
list1 = [3, 6]
```

I'd like to update `dict1` or create another list as follows:

```
dict1 = [{'domain':'Ratios', 'count':3}, {'domain':'Geometry', 'count':6}]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: According to the example, the title to this question should be: "Updating a list of python dictionaries values from another list".

From the current title I would expect that list1 = [('Ratios', 3), ('Geometry', 6)]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
>>> l1 = [{'domain':'Ratios'},{'domain':'Geometry'}]
>>> l2 = [3, 6]
>>> for d,num in zip(l1,l2):
        d['count'] = num


>>> l1
[{'count': 3, 'domain': 'Ratios'}, {'count': 6, 'domain': 'Geometry'}]
```

Another way of doing it, this time with a list comprehension which does not mutate the original:

```
>>> [dict(d, count=n) for d, n in zip(l1, l2)]
[{'count': 3, 'domain': 'Ratios'}, {'count': 6, 'domain': 'Geometry'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. The second solution yields an error in its current form

Comment: Are you using python 3? I will probably change it to be cross compatible.

Comment: which is faster computationally?

Comment: @amc It's probably not worth worrying about :P But could run some `timeit`s on it

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(dict1):
    d['count'] = list1[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
# list index
l_index=0

# iterate over all dictionary objects in dict1 list
for d in dict1:

    # add a field "count" to each dictionary object with
    # the appropriate value from the list
    d["count"]=list1[l_index]

    # increase list index by one
    l_index+=1
```

---

This solution doesn't create a new list. Instead, it updates the existing `dict1` list.

Comment: Very verbose for Python but explains everything really well.

Comment: Yes you have right! It is very verbose. But since there are other answers less verbose here, I think it would be ok to add a more explanatory solution..

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension will be the pythonic way to do it.

```
[data.update({'count': list1[index]}) for index, data in enumerate(dict1)]
```

The `dict1` will be updated with the corresponding value from `list1`.

Comment: -1 Using a list comprehension for mutations is **not** pythonic. Use a simple for loop.

Comment: update on a dict work on reference not provide output . data.update() return None. You will get out put as [None, None, ....]